# Highcharts not working after jquery upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, upgrade

we have some graphics using

```
highcharts 2.5.1 back in 2011 bundled with Jquery 1.4.2
```

and everything works **OK** but we save some other javascript plugins and they we need to upgrade them as well `latest releases have some bug fixed and we want to  take advantage of them` and they also need `Jquery upgrade as well` but when i upgrade to latest `jquery version`

`jquery-1.11.1.min` then `highcharts` seems not longer works??

what can i do to make it works as using `JQuery 1.4.2`

sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    reversed: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return ''+
                             this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                    series: [{
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
                }, {
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
                }, {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
                }]
            });                         
        });             
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
```

generates the right output

[image: Using JQuery 1.4.2]

if i change the `JQuery version` like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

generates something like.

i see something like

[image: Using jQuery 1.11]

`also tested con JQuery 1.10`

Comment: what is the issue that you are seeing? Any errors in the javascript console? Please provide adequate information in the question

Comment: i dont see the graphics and in other graphics the data is not displayed.

Comment: Code works well with the latest highcharts and jquery http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/9g3679zk/ What version of highcharts are you using? Update it to the latest available version as per your license

Comment: Highcharts version is 2.1.5

Comment: Use 2.2 @ http://code.highcharts.com/2.2/highcharts.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [compatibility page of highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility)

```
jQuery  

1.4.3 - 1.10.x for all browsers.
2.0.x for modern browsers.
```

Try using 1.10.x if you can. If you still see the issue, I would suggest create a jsFiddle demonstration of the issue & report here. SO Experts or Highcharts support team can assist you while you are using an officially supported version of jQuery.

**EDIT**

Your code works well, check out @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/9g3679zk/

You may also need to upgrade the Highcharts js

**EDIT 2**

Using Highcharts 2.1.5 @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/9g3679zk/1/ The charts don't load as you have showed, on resizing window it does redraw and chart comes up.

Upgrading to 2.2 seems to fix it @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/9g3679zk/2/ You most likely should be at be able to upgrade from 2.1 to 2.2 with your existing license.

Comment: i will try to upgrade `Highcharts.js` if it works i will mark your comment as solution. thanks a lot...